# Error: android unable to parse JSON with Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android Programming, I am trying to parse JSON with android
and trying to invoke the web service from this yahoo URL:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.quote+where+symbol+in+(%22MSFT%22)

Error: However, I get error when I try to run this simple application  on the emulator:

code:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.jsonparser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //The JSON Rest Service I will pull from:
    static String yahooStockInfo ="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";

    //Will hold the values I pull from the JSON
    static String stockSymbol = "";
    static String stockDaysLow = "";
    static String stockDaysHigh = "";
    static String stockChange = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Call for doInBackground() in MyAsyncTask to be executed
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    // Use AsyncTask if you need to perform background tasks, but also need
    // to change components on the GUI. Put the background operations in
    // doInBackground. Put the GUI manipulation code in onPostExecute
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // HTTP Client that supports streaming uploads and downloads
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());

            // Define that I want to use the POST method to grab data from
            // the provided URL
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(yahooStockInfo);

            // Web service used is defined
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Used to read data from the URL
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            // Will hold the whole all the data gathered from the URL
            String result = null;

            try {
                // Get a response if any from the web service
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // The content from the requested URL along with headers, etc.
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                // Get the main content from the URL
                inputStream = entity.getContent();

                // JSON is UTF-8 by default
                // BufferedReader reads data from the InputStream until the
                // Buffer is full
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);

                // Will store the data
                StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;

                // Read in the data from the Buffer untilnothing is left
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    // Add data from the buffer to the StringBuilder
                    theStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }

                // Store the complete data in result
                result = theStringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                // Close the InputStream when you're done with it
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}
                catch(Exception e){}
            }

            // Holds Key Value pairs from a JSON source
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                // Print out all the data read in
                // Log.v("JSONParser RESULT ", result);
                // Delete cbfunc( and ); from the results
                result = result.substring(7);
                result = result.substring(0, result.length()-2);

                // Get the root JSONObject
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                // Get the JSON object named query
                JSONObject queryJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");

                // Get the JSON object named results inside of the query object
                JSONObject resultsJSONObject = queryJSONObject.getJSONObject("results");

                // Get the JSON object named quote inside of the results object
                JSONObject quoteJSONObject = resultsJSONObject.getJSONObject("quote");

                // Get the JSON Strings in the quote object
                stockSymbol = quoteJSONObject.getString("symbol");
                stockDaysLow = quoteJSONObject.getString("DaysLow");
                stockDaysHigh = quoteJSONObject.getString("DaysHigh");
                stockChange = quoteJSONObject.getString("Change");

                // EXTRA STUFF THAT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH THE PROGRAM

                Log.v("SYMBOL ", stockSymbol);
                Log.v("Days Low ", stockDaysLow);
                Log.v("Days High ", stockDaysHigh);
                Log.v("Change ", stockChange);

                // GET ARRAY DATA
                JSONArray queryArray = quoteJSONObject.names();

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i=0; i<queryArray.length(); i++) {
                    list.add( queryArray.getString(i) );
                }

                for(String item : list){
                    Log.v("JSON ARRAY ITEMS ", item);
                }
                // END OF GET ARRAY DATA

                // Gets the first item in the JSONObject
                JSONArray objectArray = resultsJSONObject.names();

                // Prints out that first item in the JSONObject
                Log.v("JSON NEXT NODE ", objectArray.getString(0));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Gain access so I can change the TextViews
            TextView line1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.line1);
            TextView line2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.line2);
            TextView line3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.line3);

            // Change the values for all the TextViews
            line1.setText("Stock: " + stockSymbol + " : " + stockChange);
            line2.setText("Days Low: " + stockDaysLow);
            line3.setText("Days High: " + stockDaysHigh);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

code main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/line1"
  style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/line2"
 style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/line3"
  style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

please help me out, iam eager to learn

Comment: Where is your Logcat error ?

Comment: What are you trying to get in this line ` JSONArray queryArray = quoteJSONObject.names();`? What does `names()` return ?

Comment: why you used this,   `result = result.substring(7);
            result = result.substring(0, result.length()-2);`

Comment: java.lang.RunTimeException:An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: @ GrlsHu

 Delete cbfunc( and ); from the results
from the JSON file

Comment: @user2445971 What are you trying to say ?

Answer (score 0):

[The url to get json from](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22MSFT%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=)

Not knowing the actual error it's hard to see whats wrong with your code but looking at the json result from the url you are trying to parse I noticed that it doesn't start with cbfunc( which you're trying to clean up in the rows:

```
        // Delete cbfunc( and ); from the results
        result = result.substring(7);
        result = result.substring(0, result.length()-2);
```

This means you're just corrupting the json just before trying to parse it. It's better to do the clean up with regex and String.replaceFirst(...) or just plain old String.replace(...).